# Configure VIM YouCompleteMe for special project structure

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin

My C project has following structures. This is the structure for a large project, I can't change the structure. I want to use YouCompleteMe for semantic code completion for this project.

```
main/                     // folder for C file to be compiled
  |- module1.c            // module main C file.
  |- module2.c
  |- .....
module1/
  |- mod1_func1.c         // function file to be included in main module C file.
  |- mod1_func2.c
  |- mod2_func3.c
module2/
  |- mod2_func1.c
  |- mod2_func2.c
  |- mod2_func3.c
```

Content for `moduleX.c`, this will include all related header files and module related C files.

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
...
#include "modX_func1.c"
#include "modX_func2.c"
```

Content for `modX_funcX.c` has one or few function definitions. Doesn't have header included

```
// no header file included here
int modX_funcX(void) {.....}
```

Because there is not related header included, `clang` must parse `moduleX.c` in order to do code completion on `modX_funcX.c`,  I have tried `clang` code completion from command line. Command below works

```
clang -x c -fsyntax-only -code-completion-at mod1_func1.c:4:11 module1.c
```

So my question: how to configure YouCompleteMe to do code completion when I edit the `modX_funcX.c` file?

I guess modification to YouCompleteMe source might required to do this job. My current idea is to add a file mapping database with format:

```
path_of_file_to_complete:path_of_file_for_clang_to_parse
```

So before send the code completion request, get `path_of_file_for_clang_to_parse` from database based on current buffer name, pass this file name to `libclang`.

Is my idea workable? If Yes, where is exactly place to add this file mapping function?

Comment: I don't know why c is tagged

Comment: @Chinna c tag removed. Sorry about that.

Comment: Does YCM respect the vim option `'path'`?  Try editing mod1_func1.c and `:set path+=/path/to/main/module1.c`.  Does that help?  If so, then you can use an autocommand or a modeline to do this automatically.

Comment: I am not sure if YCM respect vim `path`. Even if it yes, The project has over 15000 source and header files,  this may not a proper way. And I have some similar workspaces for different product lines.

Comment: have you looked at CompilationDatabase support? it may work for you, take a look at the help... but in any case, this structure looks much lame, like trying to embed Make using includes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my project structure is really lame, as said by `pepper_chico`, but no choice, I can't change it. In the passed few days, I did some hacking to both `YouCompleteMe` and `libclang` by change the API call of `libclang` to pass `input_filename` in additional to `complte_filename`.

This is a dirty hacking, but it works for me now. In case anyone might interesting, I have write a post to briefly record down my analysis and hacking process.

- [My Post](http://zhuyong.me/blog/2014/02/20/hack-youcompleteme-and-libclang-for-lamely-structured-project/)

**Update 2015-02-03**

1 Year later, when I look back at this problem, I finally figured out a better way to hack `YouCompleteMe` for my need. Details [look here](http://zhuyong.me/blog/2015/02/01/hacked-youcompleteme-to-support-lamely-structured-pojects/)

My modification on GitHub [here](https://github.com/yongzhy/ycmd/tree/lamely), take note the branch name is `lamely` for now.